# Present ViewController on UISplitViewNavigator's MasterViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisplitviewcontroller

I've created a new XCode project using the SplitViewNavigator template. One of the MasterViewController's navigationItems should present a configuration ViewController (fullScreen on iPhone, popup on iPad).

This config controller has been created in a separate storyboard (Filter.storyboard).
In this storyboard I dragged a ViewController on the stage and embedded it in a Navigation Controller (Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller) because the config itself consists of different screens the user can go through. 
The NavigationController has been given a StoryBoard ID "FilterNavController".

I've done this several times in other applications, so this does work. Unfortunately, I can't get it working with the SplitViewNavigator template.

Here is how I try to open the filter controller once the button has been tapped, nothing special about it;

```
UIStoryboard *filterBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Filter" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *filterNavController = [filterBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FilterNavController"];
UIViewController *vc = [filterNavController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

[self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

self is the MasterViewController.

From my uneducated point of view, I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work. As I said, it does in other (non SplitViewNavigator template) applications.
The error message I'm getting is the following:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <UINavigationController: 0x7f9bab61a700>.'
```

No idea what the heck is going on here but it already cost me half a day.
Interestingly, when I just create a UIViewController on the Filter.storyboard and set its StoryBoardID, the ViewController will get presented. However, I need it to be embedded in a UINavigationController.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sakes of completeness, the following method works nicely for instantiating ViewControllers from a Storyboard.

Instead of creating a UINavigationController on the Storyboard, just create the ViewController(s) and embed them in a UINavigationController on code.

```
UIStoryboard *myBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MyViewController *menuController = [myBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myController];
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```